# Semantic Versioning for command line tools

Tags: command-line-interface, versioning, semantic-versioning

The [SemVer specs](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0.html) state that you should increase the

> 1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> 2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
> 3. PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

What is backwards-compatible in the case of a command-line interface?

#### A simplified example:

There is a command-line tool which analyzes numbers in a text file. It will return the min and max values.

Version 1.0.0 works like this:

```
$ analyzertool numbers.txt
min: 12
max: 20
```

Now I add a useful feature. The tool will now also output the average value:

```
$ analyzertool numbers.txt
min: 12
max: 20
avg: 17
```

Is this a MAJOR or MINOR change? The output has clearly been changed, but the lines with `min` and `max` are still present, so somebody doing

```
$ analyzertool numbers.txt | grep min
min: 12
```

would still see the same output.

I'm looking for existing conventions or relevant examples.

Comment: I may have answered too quickly. Does your documentation state that additional stats may eventually be appended to the output?

Comment: The 1.0.0 documentation does not announce any possibly upcoming additions.

Answer (score 1):

In the cited example, you added a feature, but did not do it in a backwards compatible way. You changed the interface by spewing more data in the reply. It's like changing the return data type of a function; it's definitely breaking. The fact that there are some use cases that won't be broken doesn't change the fact that there are others that will be.

Unless you made it emphatically clear in the documentation that additional data would be appended to the output stream as features were added, you should do a major version bump.